# ASP.NET MVC Modules as in Zend Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, zend-framework

i have learned MVC Architecture from Zend Framework, and i just started learning in ASP.NET MVC. I want to know how do i create 'modules' in ASP.NET like in Zend Framework? For example we can create Modules in Zend Framework as follows

Storeworld
-->bootstrap
-->config
-->layouts
-->modules
---->stores (Name of the Module)
------>controllers
------>forms
------>models
------>views
---->admin (Name of the Module)
------>controllers
------>forms
------>models
------>views
-->public

How can i achieve this in ASP.NET MVC 3 / 2. Please guide me.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the concept that you're looking for in ASP.NET MVC is Areas. It was introduced in ASP.NET MVC 2.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx

That link should get you started at least, but there are a lot of resources out there that should help you learn it.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is ASP.NET MVC Areas. See [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/aspnet-mvc-2-areas) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx) for more reference.